# Comparing 2 dataframes to get another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I used the `df.describe( )` on a dataframe *df* resulting in:

```
Index  count               mean          std           min            25%           max 
ABC       6                5.14         4.63             1              2            12
CDE       6                18.6         12.5             2            7.5            15
DEF       7                30.2         32.6             1            6.5            20
```

Another dataframe *df2*

```
 Index              Date        eventName    eventCount
 0            2017-08-09              ABC            24
 1            2017-08-09              CDE           140
 2            2017-08-10              CDE           150
 3            2017-08-11              DEF           200
```

Where the *threshold* column should be calculated as:

For example, for *eventName:ABC* using date: 2017-08-09(daily) in dataframe *df2* as the new index in this new dataframe, the deviation percentage for the date: 2017-08-09  to be stored in this new dataframe will be the value in *eventCount* column representing ABC in dataframe *df2*: which is 24 minus the value in *min* column in dataframe *df*  which is 1 representing ABC too: 24-1=23, then divided by eventCount value of ABC  in *df2* * (100), that is  23/24*100=95%

The resulting (new) dataframe should look like this:

```
     Index         eventName   eventCount        threshold       min
2017-08-09               ABC           24        Under 95%         1
2017-08-09               CDE          140      Under 98.5%         2
2017-08-10               CDE          150      Under 99.3%         2
2017-08-11               DEF          200      Under 99.5%         1
```

I am stuck already, how can I go about it?

Comment: *I am stuck already*... stuck with what? Where is your attempted code? SO is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) (by default `left`) for add new column and then some arithmetic operations:

```
df = df2.set_index('Date').join(df[['min']], on='eventName', how='left')
df['threshold'] = df['eventCount'].sub(df['min']).div(df['eventCount']).mul(100).round(2)
#if need preix with %
df['threshold1'] =(df['eventCount'].sub(df['min'])
                                   .div(df['eventCount'])
                                   .mul(100)
                                   .apply("Under {0:.2f}%".format))
print (df)

           eventName  eventCount  min  threshold    threshold1
Date                                                          
2017-08-09       ABC          24    1      95.83  Under 95.83%
2017-08-09       CDE         140    2      98.57  Under 98.57%
2017-08-10       CDE         150    2      98.67  Under 98.67%
2017-08-11       DEF         200    1      99.50  Under 99.50%
```

Comment: Good answer but would have been nice if OP attempted a solution to this complex wrangling and computation. Next time send a link and your hourly rate! Sometimes we answerers love interesting questions, but can hurt the learning process.

Comment: Nice suggestion by @Parfait. I had tried some things but it was nowhere near what I think I can post. I needed answers to nudge me in the right direction .